# "Range of operation" vs "operation range"

Tags: word-order

"Range of operation" vs "operation range"

"The range of operation for the compressor (...)" or "The operating range of the compressor"?

- Do they have the same interpretation?
- Can they substitute one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you use grammatically appropriate forms of the words based on context, yes, they are synonymous.

Answer (score 0):

It is a choice to use active vs passive like saying my father's house vs the house of my father; imho English language should be active.